# How do I copy an open file in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Using VB6, how do I copy a file from another computer to my computer when the file is opened by another person?

Comment: Do you mean *while* it is opened by another person?

Comment: @Ic - yes. Opened by another person

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you try to use the FileCopy statement on a currently open file, an error occurs.  However, the FileSystemObject's CopyFile function doesn't have a problem with it, so use that instead.  First, you will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (on the Project->References... menu).  Then you can do this:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

fso.CopyFile "\\someOtherComputer\share\foo.mdb", "C:\foo.mdb"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Windows API

```
Declare Function CopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
(ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long



Public Function CopyFileA(OldFileName As String, NewFileName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    If CopyFile(OldFileName, NewFileName, False) <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Error copying file", vbExclamation, 
    Else
        CopyFileA = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, but it is much easier using the FileSystemObject, and once you have started using that, you will see that there are also many other useful file system methods on that object....