# How do I copy an open file to a database using "System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()" or some other method?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I need to make to following snippet of code work in the context of an open file.  This code needs to run in an Excel add-in to write the currently open document to a database.  At line 3, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes() an error occurs indicating that the document is currently in use.  Is there an equivalent method that I can use that will work on an open document? If not, what is the solution?

```
Foo.DataClasses1DataContext db = new Foo.DataClasses1DataContext();
string ThisDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
byte[] inputBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ThisDocument);
Foo.RFP_Document rfpDocument = new Foo.RFP_Document();
rfpDocument.DocumentName = "Some Name";
rfpDocument.DocumentFile = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(inputBuffer);
db.RFP_Documents.InsertOnSubmit(rfpDocument);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Here's a link to a similar question related to VB.  [How do I copy an open file in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129965/how-do-i-copy-an-open-file-in-vb6)

Comment: I would generally avoid storing whole files in the database, especially if they are large. Why not store the files as files in a specific folder, and then (from the database) point to that filepath?

Comment: I generally do that as well.  However in this case I know that the files will always be small, <1mb.  And I want the content of each document to be searchable.

Comment: I would still claim that 1 megabyte is too large. Afterall, that's approximately 1.000.000 characters (bytes) in UTF8 encoding. Why not just search through the files themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just save a copy of the file using `Workbook.SaveCopyAs`, use this one and delete it afterwards.